# VIM: how to go to exact line on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, vim, ubuntu, terminal

I'm using `vi` on Ubuntu 12.10.  Some files are quite long so when I want to go to the middle of the file, I have to page down or scroll down.

Is there a VIM shortcut to go to an exact line number?

Comment: @vim experts. Is this really Ubuntu-/bash-/Linux-specific (as per OP tags)? I'm not using vim much, but for my uses I haven't noticed the slightest difference across Ubuntu/CentOS/Suse/Windows.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

```
:150
```

will take you to line 150 in vi

```
:1500
```

will take you to line 1500 in vi

As per the comments you may want to try

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

to get to line 150. 
which is less key strokes then 
<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
if you aren't sure what line you are on try

```
 :set nu!
```

notice the :

if you want to always see the line consider editing your vim profile. Most often

```
vi ~/.vimrc
```

and add

```
:set nu!
```

and write and quit

```
:wq
#or you could use :x
```

this can be done outside of vi. For example, if I want to delete line 5000 in a text file I could use a scripting language. For example, using sed it would be the following

```
sed -i '5000d;' inputFile.txt
```

to delete line 10 to 20 it would be

```
sed -i '10,20d;' inputFile.txt
```

notice the -i will edit the file in place. Without the -i it will goto stdout. Try it. you can redirect stdout to a file

```
sed '5001,$d;' inputFile.txt >> appenedFile.txt
```

this might have a lot going on here for you. this deletes line 5001 to $. With $ being the end of the file. >> will append to a file. where as > creates a new file.

if you are curious how many lines are in a file you may want to type `wc -l inputFile.txt`

some of this may seem awfully trivial, but if you are trying to edit a file with 50,000 lines it may take vi a sweet minute to open and traverse. where if you know you just want to delete the last line you could use sed and do it in a fraction of the time.

sed can also search and replace inside a file as well. But perhaps awk, perl, or python might also be a viable solution.

but overall, you may wan to find a good tutorial on vi. thousands exist. I'd consult google. Perhaps find yourself a VIM Cheatsheat.

Comment: No problem, I expanded on my answer a little but. Good luck

Comment: also, in vim you can type:  n50%   and get to middle of the file.

Comment: In normal mode, `150G` does the same as `:150`. It's not faster but may be easier to remember.

Comment: @romainl 150gg does the same.  Both of which are indeed faster than :150<cr>

Comment: @Randy Morris - Yes, it's faster, I forgot to take `<CR>` into account.

Comment: thanks everyone. I'm learning a lot too. I have only been using VI about a year and every day it seems like I learn something new.

Comment: `:set nu!` will *toggle* line numbers, i.e. the command will hide numbers when they are already shown. If one wants to *see* line numbers, he/she should run/add to .vimrc `:set nu` (no exclamation mark at end). Toggle mode is useful for key bindings.

Answer (score 18):

Other vim tips: in command mode

- <kbd>H</kbd> goes to the top of the screen
- <kbd>M</kbd> goes to the middle of the screen
- <kbd>L</kbd> goes to the bottom of the screen
- <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> goes to the first line
- <kbd>G</kbd> goes to the last line

Answer (score 8):

From an opened terminal, in a bash shell, simply edit your file by running:

```
$ vi +N yourfile
```

Where `N` is the line number.

For viewing (`more` or `less`;):

```
$ less +N yourfile
$ more +N yourfile
```

The sign `+` mean *command to run at start*. So if *command* is only a number, then `vi`, `less` and `more`, will jumps to this as *line number*.

But you may also use `/regex` for finding the first occurence of a specific string or regex:

```
$ less +/Error logfile
$ less -i +/error logfile      # -i Causes less's searches to ignore case
$ vi +/open.*myfile myprog...
```

Answer (score 7):

take a few minutes and start reading [this](https://vim.rtorr.com/) document. It reward you in the long run for efficiency in editing especially config file.

Comment: Link is now dead